# Unknown equation in the SPICE resistor model

Tags: resistors, dc, spice, hspice

I was looking for simple resistor spice model, and came across this:

```
parameters
+rsh = 40           dw = 0              dl = 0              
+tc1 = 0            tc2 = 0             pvc1 = 0              
+pvc2 = 0           pvc3 = 0              
...                 
+teff = 1+tc1*temp+tc2*temp*temp 
R0 ( p n ) resistor r=rsh*(l-dl)/(w-dw)*teff*(1+pvc1*(tanh(pvc2*abs(v(p,n)/(l-dl))+pvc3)-tanh(pvc3)))
```

[Source](https://www.princeton.edu/~nverma/cadenceSetup_6.1.7/gpdk090_v4.4/models/spectre/res_polywo.va)

I am pretty familiar with almost all of typical resistor parameters, but I can't find any information about that particular resistance equation and any of the "pvc" parameters. Specially about this part:

```
(1+pvc1*(tanh(pvc2*abs(v(p,n)/(l-dl))+pvc3)-tanh(pvc3)))
```

Where does this equation come from? Where can I find out more about it?

UPD:
This is probably on-silicon model

Comment: So exactly where did you "come across" this model? Give us some context.

Comment: given the 'rsh' which could be a resistance_sheet, this is an on-silicon model

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I know about 'rsh' already, but i can't really find any information about the second part of the equation

Comment: @Elliot Alderson https://www.princeton.edu/~nverma/cadenceSetup_6.1.7/gpdk090_v4.4/models/spectre/res_polywo.va
I think that a 90 nm model from the gpdk library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pvc* could be "process variation coefficient " similarly to the tc* which i'd read to be "temperature coefficient " when used in the way they are to produce a value for teff.

Comment: That sounds believable. Can you provide any additional information, links or articles about this?

Comment: Regrettably, I can't. This is purely speculation from looking at models for power devices then analysing how they're structured and how they structure equations for values such as R_ds-on.

Comment: Well, anyway, thanks. I will wait one or two days (this part of StackExchange is pretty idle sometimes) and close the question with your answer.